# How to populate values in PL/SQL collection of an object type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace type obj_emp_sal as object (salary number(10), employee_id number(3));
```

Object created. Now i need to run the below code.

```
declare
  idx number(10);
  emp_id number(3);
  v_sal number(10);
  emp_name obj_emp_sal := obj_emp_sal();
begin
  idx := 1;

  for i in (select salary,employee_id from employees) loop 
    emp_name.extend;
    emp_id := i.employee_id;
    v_sal := i.salary;
    emp_name(idx) := (v_sal,emp_id);
    --emp_name(idx).salary := v_sal;
    --emp_name(idx).employee_id := emp_id;
    idx := idx+1;
  end loop;

 for j in 1..emp_name.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Emp Id - '||emp_name(j).employee_id||' And Salary = 
'||emp_name(j).salary);
  end loop;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_name.count);
exception
  when others then
    null;
end;
```

This code is getting error as shown below. Someone please help and let me know, how the values are populated into a collection which is initialized as an object with more than 1 arguments.

```
 Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 27:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OBJ_EMP_SAL'
ORA-06550: line 5, column 12:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 22, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a collection type in your code. You can declare and use one with something like:

```
type tab_emp_sal is table of obj_emp_sal;
emp_sals tab_emp_sal := tab_emp_sal();
```

and then populate that with instances of the object type:

```
emp_sals(idx) := obj_emp_sal(v_sal,emp_id);
```

So put together:

```
declare
  idx number(10);
  emp_id number(3);
  v_sal number(10);

--  emp_name obj_emp_sal := obj_emp_sal();
  type tab_emp_sal is table of obj_emp_sal;
  emp_sals tab_emp_sal := tab_emp_sal();
begin
  idx := 1;

  for i in (select salary,employee_id from employees) loop 
    emp_sals.extend;
    emp_id := i.employee_id;
    v_sal := i.salary;
    emp_sals(idx) := obj_emp_sal(v_sal,emp_id);
    idx := idx+1;
  end loop;

  for j in 1..emp_sals.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Emp Id - '||emp_sals(j).employee_id
      ||' And Salary = '||emp_sals(j).salary);
  end loop;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_sals.count);
-- don't do this...
--exception
--  when others then
--    null;
end;
/
```

Having a exception handler that catches everything is not a good idea - it is occasionally useful if you want to log any errors to another table and then re-raise the exception, but otherwise all you are doing is hiding any errors that are thrown and making it impossible to (a) know than a problem occurred or (b) debug it.

---

You could also bulk-collect from your query directly into the collection - notice the call to the object constructor in the query:

```
declare
  type tab_emp_sal is table of obj_emp_sal;
  emp_sals tab_emp_sal := tab_emp_sal();
begin
  select obj_emp_sal(salary,employee_id)
  bulk collect into emp_sals
  from employees;
  
  for j in 1..emp_sals.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Emp Id - '||emp_sals(j).employee_id
      ||' And Salary = '||emp_sals(j).salary);
  end loop;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_sals.count);
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=96af39b2dab0d9285f7d3a461a68b7a9)